# Token (WindowsIdentity Get Administrator().Token)

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте
Хочу запустить из службы программу от имени администратора (простой запуск отлично работает).

```
   IntPtr token = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;
```

Возвращает Token без Админ привилегии.
В просторах Стековерфлов нашел токой код(уже точно не помню где именно)

```
public static bool Launch(string appCmdLine /*,int processId*/)
        {

            bool ret = false;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            //Either specify the processID explicitly
            //Or try to get it from a process owned by the user.
            //In this case assuming there is only one explorer.exe

            Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
            int processId = -1;//=processId
            if (ps.Length > 0)
            {
                processId = ps[0].Id;
            }

            if (processId > 1)
            {
                token = GetPrimaryToken(processId);
                if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    IntPtr envBlock = GetEnvironmentBlock(token);
                    ret = LaunchProcessAsUser(appCmdLine, token, envBlock, 4);
                    if (envBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
                        DestroyEnvironmentBlock(envBlock);

                    CloseHandle(token);
                }

            }
            return ret;
        }
private static IntPtr GetPrimaryToken(int processId)
        {
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool retVal = false;
            Process p = null;

            try
            {
                p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
            }

            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                string details = String.Format("ProcessID {0} Not Available", processId);
                //Debug.WriteLine(details);
                throw;
            }

            //Gets impersonation token
            retVal = OpenProcessToken(p.Handle, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref token);
            if (retVal == true)
            {

                SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                sa.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

                //Convert the impersonation token into Primary token
                retVal = DuplicateTokenEx(
                token,
                TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_QUERY,
                ref sa,
                (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification,
                (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                ref primaryToken);

                //Close the Token that was previously opened.
                CloseHandle(token);
                if (retVal == false)
                {
                    string message = String.Format("DuplicateTokenEx Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    Debug.WriteLine(message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string message = String.Format("OpenProcessToken Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                Debug.WriteLine(message);
            }
            //We'll Close this token after it is used.
            return primaryToken;

        }
```

Тут в место "explorer" написать программу запущенный от имени Администратора то все нормально, запускает программу который без Админа не работает.
Меня такой подход не устраивает.

Как получить Token Администратора по другому???
(Уже третий день не могу сделать)

Comment: тоесть вы хотите хакнуть винду вот прямо так? в лоб?

Comment: А что? думаете нельзя?

Comment: безопастность винды ушла дальше, чем думают многие юниксоиды

Comment: То есть хотите сказать, ну, не как нельзя?

Comment: Думаю, что для этого необходимо как минимум приложению иметь права админские